# Найти строку с наибольшим количеством слов

Tags: c++, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне найти строку с максимальным количеством слов и вывести этот результат (текст считывается с файла)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>


#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
using namespace std;


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int otv;
    do {
        cout << "1.Кодировка" << endl << "2.Декодировка" << endl << "0.Выход" << endl;
        int count;
        cin >> count;
        if (count != 1 && count != 2 && count != 0) {
            cout << endl << "Будьте внимательней!" << endl << endl;
        }
        switch (count) {
            case 1: {
                string s;
                int strok = 0;
                int max = 0;
                ifstream book("text.txt");
                if (book.is_open()) {
                    cout << endl << "Текст загружен!" << endl << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "Текст не загружен!" << endl << endl;
                }
                while (getline(book, s)) {
                    strok++;
                }
                cout << "Количество строк :" << strok << endl << "Максимальное количество слов в строке :" << max << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                break;
            }
            case 0: {
                exit(0);
            }
        }

    } while (otv = 1);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Первым делом удалите всю ерунду, что вы написали...

Answer (score 2):

Ну если использовать `STL` то ответ вот: (Все закоментрировано)

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


//Разделить строку по пробелам
std::vector<std::string> splitStr(std::string s)
{
    std::vector<std::string> strs; //Вектор строк
    size_t pos = 0; //Итератор
    while ((pos = s.find(" ")) != std::string::npos) { //Повторять пока не найдено пробелов
        strs.push_back(s.substr(0, pos)); //Добавить строку в вектор
        s.erase(0, pos + 1); //Удалить значение из строки
    }
    return strs; // Вернуть вектор строк
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> a {"This is the longest", "a a a a a a", "Tiny", "Medium"}; //Вектор для примера

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = std::max_element( //Найти максимальный элемент
        a.begin(), // Начало вектора `a`
        a.end(),  // Конец вектора `a`
        [](std::string &A, std::string &B) // Лямбда функция с 2 параметрами
        {
            return splitStr(A).size()<splitStr(B).size(); //Вернуть если размер разделенной строки A меньше размера разделенной строки B
        }
    );

    std::cout << *it << std::endl; // Вывести значение
}
```

Если говорить о 'ванильных' методах, то вот (тоже закоментировано)

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>




int main()
{
    int size = 4; // Размер массива
    std::string *a = new std::string[size] {"This is the longest", "a a a a a a", "Tiny", "Medium"}; //Массив строк `a`

    int max_spaces = 0; //Максимальное кол-во пробелов найдено
    int max_index = 0; //Индекс с максимальным кол-вом пробелов

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        int currentSpaces = 0; //Кол-во пробелов у текущей строки
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == ' ')
            {
                currentSpaces++;
            }
        }

        if (currentSpaces > max_spaces) //Если у текущей строки больше пробелов
        {
            max_index = i; // То максимальный индекс равен i (текущая строка)
        }
    }

    std::cout << a[max_index]; // Вывести
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#ТакойСебеКод

```
#include <iostream>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    const unsigned int size = 5;
    std::string str[size] = {"sdad sad ",
                          "sad sa da",
                          " adawfs sd  sdfds r crc rc ",
                          " ",
                          " dsa"};

    int word[size] ={0};
    bool state = OUT;

    for (unsigned int i =0; i < size; ++i){
        for(char it: str[i]){
            if(it == ' ' || it == '\n' || it == '\t'){
                state = OUT;
            }
            else if(state == OUT){
                state = IN;
                ++word[i];
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Слов в строке " << i << ":"<< word[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```